# Using ArcGIS to gain information about species locations

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am totally new to ArcGIS so I'm really sorry if this a stupid question.

I am a conservation biologist and I've got a GDB database, with a bunch of species ranges on it.

The output I desire from this, is a list of countries where the species live. So a list of countries that each ranges covers.

Can anyone tell me how I would go about getting this? I've been googling how to use ArcGIS guides and getting nowhere...

Comment: +1 for a conservation biology question.  How many species are you dealing with?  This may help determine whether or not you can use the built-in Select By Location tool under the Selection tab or a more complicated automated approach.

Comment: Thousands. But if there is only a 'slow' way to do it I'd be happy to hear it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Overlay analysis is a very common type of problem in the GIS field.  ArcGIS 10.2 help has a good description of various [overlay analysis methods](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018p00000004000000).  In your case, I would begin by performing an [identity](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000n000000) of the species polygons and the country polygons.

*From ArcGIS help 10.2*:

> Computes a geometric intersection of the input features and identity
>   features. The input features or portions thereof that overlap identity
>   features will get the attributes of those identity features.

From there you can query the attribute table and summarize the results

*Additional Information*:

[An overview of the Overlay toolset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000009000000)

Comment: It's worth noting that the Identity tool is only available with the Advanced license.  See [this response](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/66638/7424) by @PolyGeo to emulate the Identity tool with Basic or Standard licenses.